# How to include the Trix styles in Rails when using Propshaft and DartSass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext, propshaft

I include action_text in application.js:

```
// application.js
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
```

I'm showing the editor using simple_form like this:

```
 <%= f.rich_text_area :body %>
```

But it shows as plain text buttons with no styles included at all.

The Guide says:

> The trix stylesheet will be included together with Action Text styles
> in your application.css file.

But it isn't, probably because I have an application.scss file, not .css and I'm not using sprockets.

How do I import the trix/action_text editor styles into my sass or otherwise include it on the page when using propshaft and Sass?

Answer (score 0):

ok, worked it out (ie tried everything until I stumbled on the obvious answer).

```
// application.scss
@import "trix";
```